# Enabling saveenv command in u-boot for baltos ir2110

Tags: u-boot

I am using baltos ir2110. I am compiling u-boot-2017.01 with am335x_baltos_defconfig for u-boot. My problem is that saveenv command is not available with this configuration of u-boot. Is there any specific reason for this? Also how should turn it on ? Recompiling u-boot is not a problem for me but I am not finding the right configuration for enabling saveenv.
I have tried with adding CONFIG_CMD_SAVEENV=y in the configuration file.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the hardware. Do you know where the environment is saved? The u-boot needs to know how to write to this storage, which can be tricky for certain hardware.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the version of u-boot. The u-boot-2017-01 version does not support environment macros configuration from the configuration file. This has to be done in the header file for the specific board, baltos.h in my case.

The following addition in baltos.h made it work:

```
#define CONFIG_ENV_SIZE                 (128 << 10)
#define CONFIG_ENV_IS_IN_FAT
#define FAT_ENV_INTERFACE               "mmc"
#define FAT_ENV_DEVICE_AND_PART         "0.0"
#define FAT_ENV_FILE                    "uboot.env"

/*#define CONFIG_ENV_IS_NOWHERE*/
```

The newer versions of u-boot support configuring the environment from a config file.